# Why does one chart overlays another (chart.js)?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I wanted to create one chart and update type. But when I update `pie` chart type to `bar` both charts are visible

```js
function rebuildExpensesChart(){
    let ct = document.getElementById("chartType").value

    ExpensesChartConfig.data.datasets = [{
        type: ct,
        //some code here...
    }]
    ExpensesChartConfig.data.labels = someLabels
    ExpensesChart.update()
    console.log(ExpensesChart)
}
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRx1i.png)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P6gR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with adding this:

```js
    ExpensesChart.data = null
    ExpensesChart.options = null
    ExpensesChart.update()
```

before the main code